# FCM - Send push notifications - IOS ANDROID

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new in **IOS** (swift) and **Android**. I have read about **FCM** (Firebase Cloud Messaging). I would send *push notifications one to one*. I know that it is dangerous using my firebase server key. 
So, what I can do to send push notifications device to device? 
Maybe I can use a custom server? I would have some informations about this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the two devices on the same account on the database?

Comment: No one device to another

Comment: Sending device-to-device messages will require a server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging. I highly recommend reading [this post on the Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html). While it talks about Android-to-Android device messaging, the exact same approach (and the same server-side script) will work for iOS too.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see that

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : I'm not expert in this field and so I would have some hints. I have had little experience with xampp working locally but my server should be online 24h to send messages between smartphones. how can I create or recover a server which should be always online? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: The blog post I linked you to doesn't use XAMPP, but a simple node script. I you search for hosts that can run custom node script you will find hundreds of options. Recommending one is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but there are bound to be plenty of review sites.