# Notification when change is detected in android

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, synchronization, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-background

I would like to send a notification in every state (app in background or running) when some data in firebase are changed the database. Do I need to use push notification from firebase? 
I use the xxx.keepSync(true) to sync with the firebase db. May I use this detect the change and how can I send the notification in the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase cloud functions.
Refer to firebase documentation for details.

Comment: I need to detect the change of firebase in another server or I send send a request to another server and it send a request to firebase to send the push notification?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you said.

Comment: Exactly what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Like Facebook or instragram. When people comment on their post, the owner would get the notifications. When people post a new post, it would send the notification to all the users

Comment: Such kind of implementation can be easily implemented using firebase realtime db and cloud messaging. Check out firebase documentation for more info.  Visit firebase.google.com

Comment: but they only show how to send notification directly from firebase to phone but how can I automatically send the notification?

Comment: Make a http request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send  with the required headers on the onDataChange method in firebase. For more info visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging