# How can I send notification to another mobile device via FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building two apps, one for booking a haircut and one for the barbers to respond to the haircuts requested by the clients, as soon as the client tap on the "Book Haircut" button it should send a request notification to the barber whom he picked, but I don't know how to do it, I don't know anything about notifications. Please help guys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42390956/6490462

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer my ans from here..

you need these things before send push

> 1. receiver token
> 2. Legacy server key

else follow this link..

[See my Ans for send push to specific device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/42452064#42452064)