# How to send notification from a device to multiple devices Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code snippet here to send a notification from a device to multiple devices:

```
public static void sendNotificationToUser(final String message) {

    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://danger-alarm.firebaseio.com/");
    final Firebase notifications = ref.child("danger-alarm");

    Map notification = new HashMap<>();
    notification.put("message",message);

    notifications.push().setValue(notification);
}
```

How my Firebase database looks like:

[image: How my Firebase database looks like]

But the problem is, when I execute these codes, it doesn't send anything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging did you try this?

Comment: I have a problem with the **builder()** method in the code snippets

Comment: This syntax `new Firebase("https://danger-alarm.firebaseio.com/")` is over four years old. Please find a newer Firebase tutorial to follow, or use the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start.

Comment: @amin OP is not using FCM, but the Realtime Database.