# Sending push notification to a specific user using firebase with expo notifications

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications to a certain user when a certain function executes !
I have seen that Firebase cloud messaging is no supported on IOS , so i switched to `expo-notifications` and i have seen tutorials but all of them require a backend server to send these notifications ! and m using firebase as my backend ( firebase firestore ) ! So can that be possible to do with firebase only ?

I wanna send the notification when this function executes

```
const onCancel = async (dateDetails) => {
   setIsSubmitting(true);
   if (!dateDetails.accepted) {
     await deleteDoc(doc(db, "Dates", dateDetails.dateId)).then(() => {
       setIsSubmitting(false);
       Toast.show({
         topOffset: 60,
         type: "success",
         text1: "Date Deleted Successfully",
         text2: " ",
       });
     });
     fetchMyDates().then((res) => {
       setNewDatesOnChild(res);
     });
     //Show a toast
   } else {
     setIsSubmitting(false);
     Alert.alert(
       "Your order has already been accepted Please call this number to Cancel your order !"
     );
   }
 };
```

If there is another way of sending push notifications Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The Expo documentation on [sending notifications](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/) is pretty clear that you should call its backend from your own backend, so not from the client-side app directly.

[image]

In that sense it seems very similar to sending messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging, which shows this diagram for the same use-case:

[image]

Here too the calls must come from a trusted environment, and can't be secure made from the client-side app itself.

For more on this, including examples how to implement the sending of messages in a trusted environment, see:

- [How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging)
- [Firebase push notification device to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315275/firebase-push-notification-device-to-device)
- [Device to device push notifications logic Swift IOS Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654011/device-to-device-push-notifications-logic-swift-ios-firebase)