# How do I call the Firebase Cloud Messaging API from my ReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, rest, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have a ReactJS and React Native apps connected to the same back-end (firebase), and I've set up everything on the mobile app to receive a notification that is triggered from the React app, however, I'm unable to trigger the Cloud Messaging API from the React App, according to the documentation there are 2 ways, Firebase Admin SDK and REST API, but Firebase Admin isn't working because apparently it can't be used on the client side code, and I have no knowledge in REST API, or how it works in React, I tried searching for an example code but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to securely send messages directly from one client to an other with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

**Sending** messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging requires that you specify the FCM server key or specify the administrative credentials for the project. Both of these can only securely be done on a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

Also see:

- [Firebase push notification device to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315275/firebase-push-notification-device-to-device/63317003#63317003)
- [How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990140/how-to-send-one-to-one-message-using-firebase-messaging)
- [How to send device to device messages using Firebase Cloud Messaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Comment: Can do this using a Callable Cloud Function that I can call from my client side with the appropriate data passed? If so that would be great, and do you have any article that can help me do it?

Comment: Can I use the Firebase Admin SDK with Cloud Functions? Will it be possible in a ReactJs app?

Comment: I was actually able to do it through Callable Cloud Functions, and it's working perfectly, thanks for the tips :)