# Send push notifications from a web application to those who have downloaded mobile application, without access to mobile app code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase, push-notification

I have a web app and used appmysite to create a mobile app. I want a user to be able to use my web application and send push notifications to those who have downloaded the mobile, but I am not able to edit the actual code of the mobile app.

I have been trying to use Firebase and I successfully got the mobile app connected and able to receive notifications from the Firebase console, and I am able to connect my ASP.NET Web application to the the same Firebase project, but I do not know how to get the "registration tokens" required to make the API call from the web app. Everything I have read on how to get the registration tokens require writing code on the mobile app to store it somewhere, but Firebase already has it so why can't I access it on the backend?

Comment: Getting the token in a web client is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that is for sending notifications in the browser though, correct? I want to use a browser (web app) to send notifications to phones who downloaded the mobile app (essentially replicate feature in firebase console.)

Comment: There is no way to send a notification directly from one device to another through FCM. That'd be a pretty big security risk, as anyone could then send any message to any of your users. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315275/firebase-push-notification-device-to-device