# Does Cloud Firestore keep a listener attached if the app is backgrounded or closed?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a SwiftUI app where I attach a listener to a document when a user logs in (I'm using Firebase Auth and email/password sign in). I remove the listener when the user signs out. My users typically stay signed in unless certain events happen to explicitly trigger sign out. ***My question is what happens to the listener if the user just backgrounds the app or closes out of it completely? Is it automatically removed at some point or does it stay attached indefinitely?*** I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this in the documentation.

I'm asking this because I don't know if I should use scenePhase to determine when the app is backgrounded, so that I can manually remove the listener and then reattach it later. I'm not sure whether leaving it open or performing remove/reattach is better in terms of performance and resource usage. I know that I'll have to decide that myself based on my logic and application flow. However, I would like to know exactly how Cloud Firestore behaves. Does anyone know and/or have documentation that they can point me toward?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494395/can-you-listen-to-firestore-updates-when-ios-app-is-in-the-background?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, thank you. I saw that post also. I've been digging around all morning in StackOverflow and elsewhere. Do you happen to know about how long an app has to be in the background before it gets killed by the OS? Does the listener get removed automatically then? My app checks to see whether a listener is attached or not once the user opens it again. So, that's not an issue for me. I just don't want there to be a resource drain for my users if the listener remains active for a long time. I'm not sure what the best practice is here or what Firebase recommends.

Comment: On how long an app can be active, search is your friend: https://www.google.com/search?q=iOS%3A+how+long+an+app+can+be+in+the+background+before+it+gets+killed+by+the+OS%3F. The best practice is to **not** depends on background listeners, but rather use FCM/APNS to send messages to the app from the server when a relevant activity happens, e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens, which is also what Doug recommends in his answer to the question I linked before.

Comment: I read Doug's post and all the others. However, for this particular app, I do not really need to use FCM/APNS to message about recent activity. That would unnecessarily complicate the logic. I just really wanted to know if the listener got removed automatically when the app was closed or sent to into the background. It seems like there's no solid answer. I'll do more research and see if scenePhase can assist with what I'm trying to do and then calculate the pro/cons performance-wise.